# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: rg.zeroturnaround:jrebel-maven-plugin:1.1.8

Tags: java, maven, alfresco, jrebel

Estoy intentando crear un gestor documental. He creado un proyecto con eclipse en Maven y he seleccionando el arquetipo `org.alfresco.maven.archetype:alfresco-share-jar-archetype` ya que me idea es aprovechar las funcionalidades de alfresco en mi propia pagina web.

Al generar el proyecto me aparece el siguiente error en el archivo `pom.xml`

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
>
> org.zeroturnaround:jrebel-maven-plugin:1.1.8:generate (execution:
>
> generate-rebel-xml, phase: process-resources)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A que se debe este error?¿Como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Hola, esta respuesta en ingles te podría ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin

Comment: Por favor pon tu imágen como texto, no todo le mundo puede verla.